# Chatter Group security permissions

Tags: chatter, security, permissions

Salesforce seems to lack a security model around a records and their children as it pertains to Chatter groups (Salesforce user groups have one).

`Chatter groups` can't own `sObjects` that secures them from access by non-group members.

Do people just avoid using chatter groups to collaborate around sObjects? Or do they implement standard `groups` whenever they need security around an object?

Thoughts?

Comment: why wounldn't you do the collab on the sobject record itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jordan, Very good question.  It's been awhile since I've worked on Chatter groups, but I recall the same limitation.  Our solution, as you suggest, was to "link" the Chatter groups to a standard group and control sharing access that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a big problem with Chatter that is affecting both customer adoption and the options for developers building Chatter-integrated apps.

Please vote for the [idea to get it fixed](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iWGvAAM) and hopefully we can get some attention from Salesforce.